# Is there any difference between ‘twisted, knotted up, spent, exhausted, pure solid burnt out’?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, differences, adjectives, books

In Donal Ryan’s book ‘The Spinning Heart’ there is such description: “…she died, twisted and knotted up and spent, exhausted, pure solid burnt out from him.”
I wonder if these adjectives are synonymous, and therefore mean ‘worn out’. Are there any differences among them?

Here is the context: “She even softened my father. How did you pull her, he wanted to know. She won’t stay with you. She’s too good for you. You’re her bit of rough, he said. All women goes through this auld phase. Ya, I thought, like my mother, except her auld phase didn’t end until she died, twisted and knotted up and spent, exhausted, pure solid burnt out from him.”

Comment: They can all mean "worn out" or "exhausted", but each term has its own unique connotations.

Comment: In relation to a person, [**twisted²**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/twisted) is rather different from [**knotted⁴**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/knotted). Neither of them mean anything like **exhausted**.